# How to use multiple controller in one getx bindin and how it specified in router page?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

`I have one home page.Which at the bottom navigation ,there is three navigation.Home, Profile, and dashboard.
I want to use three different controllers for these pages.
But I want to know that the controller is disposed of when the page is navigating to another page.
can I use my binding like this?

```
 class NavigationBarBinding implements Bindings {
   @override
   void dependencies() {
    Get.lazyPut<NavigationBarController>(() => HomeController()); 
    Get.lazyPut<NavigationBarController>(() => ProfileController());
   Get.lazyPut<NavigationBarController>(() => DashboardController());
  }
}
```

How it is specified on the router page? I am new in getx.I want to know can I dispose the controller?.

[image: dashboard]

How to handle the controller properly?
How to use this controller with the pages?(I mean ,with GetView)

I want to know when I am navigating from the home to profile page,then I am moving back to the home page, then will the data on the home page persist or not?`

Comment: not using  lazyPut    Controller . you can define  main .dart  file and   Using  Get.Fiend  method  any  Controller